# search filter and listview in nativescript with angular

Tags: nativescript-angular

I am new to `nativescript`!

I am trying to implement a search filter with `listview` in `nativescript-angular`, but I am not getting result filter from `listview`. My HTML component files' code follows.

Here I take searchbar component and listview for showing on screen (home.html):

```html
<ActionBar title="Search" class="action-bar">
 <SearchBar hint="Enter search term here"
        [text]="searchTerm" (textChange)="onTextChanged($event)" 
        (clear)="onClear($event)" (submit)="onSubmit($event)"    > 
 </SearchBar>
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout backgroundColor="#66cdaa" padding="5">
    <!-- <Label text="Select country"></Label> -->
    <listView [items]="dataItems"
        suggestMode="Suggest" displayMode="Tokens" backgroundColor="yellow" hint="serch suggestion">
        <SuggestionView tkAutoCompleteSuggestionView>
            <ng-template tkSuggestionItemTemplate let-item="item">
                <StackLayout orientation="vertical" padding="10">
                    <Label [text]="item.text"></Label>
                </StackLayout>
            </ng-template>
        </SuggestionView>
    </listView>
</StackLayout>
```

My home.component.ts file code:

```js
import { Component, ViewChild,OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { ObservableArray } from "tns-core-modules/data/observable-array";
import { TokenModel, AutoCompleteCompletionMode, AutoCompleteDisplayMode, AutoCompleteSuggestMode } from "nativescript-ui-autocomplete";

import { SearchBar } from "tns-core-modules/ui/search-bar";

export class BrowseComponent  {
    data = [];
    name="countries"
    searchPhrase: string;
    private _items: ObservableArray<TokenModel>;
    private countries = ["Australia", "Albania", "Austria", "Argentina", Maldives", 
        "Bulgaria", "Belgium", "Cyprus", "Italy", "Japan", "Denmark", "Finland", 
        "France", "Germany", "Greece", "Hungary", "Ireland", "Saudi Arabia",
        "Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia",
        "Slovenia","South Africa","South Korea","Spain","Sri Lanka",
        "St Kitts &amp; Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","St Lucia","Sudan", 
        "Suriname", "Swaziland", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Syria", "Taiwan", 
        "Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor","Togo","Tonga",
        "Trinidad &amp; Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan",
        "Turks &amp; Caicos","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates",
        "United Kingdom","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Venezuela","Vietnam",
        "Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
```

Here, I take country array and I am trying to filter this country list from html but I am not getting how to implement:

```js
constructor() {  
    this.initDataItems();
    // Use the component constructor to inject providers.
}
```

These are the functions from searchbar:

```js
onSumit(args) {
    const searchBar = args.object as SearchBar;
    console.log(`Searching for ${searchBar.text}`);
}

onTextChanged(dataItem) {
    const searchBar = dataItem as SearchBar;
    console.log(`Input changed! New value: ${dataItem}`);
}

onClear(args) {
    const searchBar = args.object as SearchBar;
    console.log(`Clear event raised`);
}

get dataItems(): ObservableArray<TokenModel> {
    return this._items;
}
```

Here this is observable Array I take:

```js
private initDataItems() {
    this._items = new ObservableArray<TokenModel>();

    for (let i = 0; i < this.countries.length; i++) {
        this._items.push(new TokenModel(this.countries[i], undefined));
    }
    ngOnInit(): void {
        // Init your component properties here.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
GlobalCompanyArrList: Array<Company>;

onTextChanged(dataItem) {
    const searchBar = dataItem as SearchBar;
    const searchValue = searchBar.text.toLowerCase();
        let arrayItems=this.GlobalCompanyArrList; //Set Main countries Arraylist data to Local Arraylist for Searching
        this.companylist_arr=new Array();
        if (searchValue !== "") {
            for (let i = 0; i < arrayItems.length; i++) {
                if (arrayItems[i].NAME.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchValue) !== -1) {
                    this.companylist_arr.push(arrayItems[i]);
                }
            }
        }
        console.log("SearchBar text changed! New value: " + searchBar.text);
}
```